# How to delay Docker (docker.service) start until USB SSD is ready on RPi?

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, docker

I've moved the Docker root to a mounted USB SSD but this appears to have stopped Docker starting on reboot:

```
root@rpi64:~# journalctl -u docker.service -b
-- Journal begins at Sat 2021-10-30 20:46:14 AWST, ends at Thu 2021-12-16 14:01:00 AWST. --
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 16 13:39:25 rpi64 dockerd[1038]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:25.010377383+08:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
Dec 16 13:39:25 rpi64 dockerd[1038]: mkdir /var/lib/docker: file exists
Dec 16 13:39:25 rpi64 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 16 13:39:25 rpi64 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 16 13:39:25 rpi64 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.


root@rpi64:~# journalctl -u containerd -b
-- Journal begins at Sat 2021-10-30 20:46:14 AWST, ends at Thu 2021-12-16 14:03:45 AWST. --
Dec 16 13:39:20 rpi64 systemd[1]: Starting containerd container runtime...
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.752645273+08:00" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.846710940+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.content.v1.content\">
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.848228792+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.860678255+08:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.860837088+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.861426995+08:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.861515051+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devma>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.867431810+08:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.867552495+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.nativ>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.869033051+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overl>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.872825736+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\">
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.873335273+08:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.873430995+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt\"..>
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.873554181+08:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata >
Dec 16 13:39:22 rpi64 containerd[579]: time="2021-12-16T13:39:22.873596514+08:00" level=info msg="metadata content store policy set" policy=shared
```

I've added: "local-fs.target" to "After=" in /lib/systemd/system/docker.service, but this hasn't fixed it.

What else can I try?

Comment: You don’t say what the mountpoint name is, or how it is mounted.  You could use “[Unit]\nAfter=mountpointname.mount” in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/usbrequires.conf if you have it defined in systemd.

Comment: @jsbillings, thanks, yes that is similar to the solution I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this comment](https://github.com/openmediavault/openmediavault/issues/458#issuecomment-628076472), I added:

```
After=media-usb.mount media-ssd.mount
Requires=media-usb.mount media-ssd.mount
```

To:

```
/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

From "unit files":

```
$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files|grep mount
media-ssd.mount                                                               generated       -
media-usb.mount                                                               generated       -
```

Matching mount points:

```
$ df -kh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       361G   85G  258G  25% /media/ssd
/dev/sdb1       7.3G  1.3G  5.7G  18% /media/usb
```

Comment: You should not directly modify any service files in `/lib/systemd`: every time a package that installed them gets updated, your changes will get wiped out. Instead, either create an override file with your desired changes in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/` or if you want to entirely replace the standard configuration, copy the `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` and edit the copy: it will then completely override the original in `/lib/systemd`.

Comment: @telcoM I did see something about the override file but couldn't make sense of how it worked and, so, avoided it.

For instance, does a file containing a single option, e.g.  After=media-usb.mount, override the entire configuration of /lib/systemd/system/docker.service? Does it add that single argument to the other arguments of "After="?

Comment: If your file is `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service`, it completely replaces `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`. If you create an override file at `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/*.conf`, then it adds to or replaces only the options listed within. For options that can have multiple values (like `After=`), the default is to add to the existing, but if your override contains first `After=` with nothing after the `=`, then `After=media-usb.mount`, then the original `After=` dependencies are ignored and only the dependencies you specify will take effect.